# Sign Up with google account to Firebase-based Web App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication

It seems that Firebase only provides the way to sign **IN** an app with Firebase as BaaS. I'm not sure if I missed something; if so, let me know what I can use to sign **UP** a new account with Google but it should be different the manner we sign **IN** to it.

If there isn't a solution, please let me know how I can customize a Sign-up function.

This is what I am using now:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication is only focussed on **authenticating** a user, so for them to prove who they are by providing their credentials. For OAuth providers (such as Google) the user already provided those credentials elsewhere, so there is no need for them to sign **up** with Firebase Authentication. All that is needed is the credentials from the OAuth provider, as in the code you've shown.

If you want the users to register with your app, that is definitely possible but is separate from their signing in with Firebase Authentication. You'll want to put up a form where you gather the registration information about the user, and then store that in a database of your choice for later look up.

Comment: That makes sense! But actually I kind of want to see the effect of using an existing Google account to sign up, like [Udacity](http://udacity.com) does. I see they handle signing up/in differently if a user uses a third-party account i.e. Google. So since Firebase doesn't provide sign-up option, what BaaS solution do you recommend?

Comment: You can try to have a look at the website of Udacity, create an account using Google if you didn't have one. And then log out and try signing up using the same Google account. I'm sure you see the difference from Firebase.

Comment: If they do something else than in your code, it's because they wrote the code to do so. You can definitely detect if you've seen the user before, and show them a registration form if this is their first visit. That part just has nothing to do with the Firebase Authentication API.

Comment: Understood. That's why I am looking for alternative for FIrebase. Any ideas, sir?